# Why doesn't my newest cloudrun revision receive traffic?

Tags: gunicorn, google-cloud-run

I am trying to deploy a Python (Gunicorn) application on CloudRun (fully managed).
Most of the time the newest deployed revision receives 100% of traffic directly after I run the deploy command.
However, from time to time, the deploy commands says the newest revision receives 0% of traffic (and when I try to reach the application, I am indeed redirected to an older version).

```
gcloud beta run deploy my-app \
  --platform=managed \
  --allow-unauthenticated \
  --project my-project \
  --region europe-west1 \
  --port=80 \
  --memory=1Gi \
  --service-account my-app@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
  --min-instances=1 \
  --image=europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/my-registry/my-app:latest

Deploying container to Cloud Run service [my-app] in project [my-project] region [europe-west1]
Service [my-app] revision [my-app-00044-zay] has been deployed and is serving 0 percent of traffic.
```

Why doesn't my revision receive traffic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have previously used `--no-traffic` this is working as intended as this option is persistent.
Try running `gcloud run services update-traffic --to-latest`

Reference doc: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy#--no-traffic

Comment: Indeed, when you play with traffic splitting/management, the newest version doesn't serve automatically 100% of the traffic

Comment: Thanks a lot ! A version of the application was indeed deployed via the console without the checkbox `serve this revision immediately` checked. All the revisions deployed after that one didn't receive traffic. The update-traffic command solved it.